# I am trying to write friend function for adding 2 complex numbers in C++

Tags: c++, friend-function

I am trying to write friend function for adding two complex numbers for my class test.

```
// Example program
 #include <iostream>

 using namespace std;

class complex{
public:
int real;
int imag;
complex():real(0),imag(0){}
complex(int i, int j)
{
    real = i;
    imag = j;
}

void getdata(){
    cout<<"Enter the Real and Imaginary part"<<endl;
    cout<<"Real : ";
    cin>>real;
    cout<<"Imaginary : ";
    cin>>imag;
    cout<<endl;
}

void display(){
    cout<<real<<"+"<<imag<<"i"<<endl;
}

friend complex friendfun(complex&, complex&);
};


complex friendfun(complex&c1,complex&c2){
c1.real=c1.real+c2.real;
c1.imag=c1.imag+c2.imag;
return c1;
}

int main(){
complex c1,c2;
c1.getdata();
c2.getdata();
cout<<"C1 : ";
c1.display();
cout<<"C2 : ";
c2.display();

c1.friendfun(c1,c2);
cout<<"After addition by friend fun"<<endl;
c1.display();
}
```

I am getting:

> 49:8: error: 'class complex' has no member named 'friendfun'

How do I fix this?

Comment: Instead of using a friend function (friendfun) you can use operator overloading. It will make your code much more efficient and more readable. You also won't have to face this kind of problems.

Comment: @TanmoyKrishnaDas How will it make the code more efficient?

Comment: Seriously man, don't you think writing c1+c2 (in case of addition) or c1+=c2 (equivalent to his code) is much more efficient and maintainable than calling a friend function which does exactly the same thing? It is not like he is using the function in other classes. Unnecessary friend functions often leads to unintentional human errors. In his code he is changing the value of c1 when he might be wanting to just show the result of the addition (which he can do by writing `cout << (c1+c2).display() << endl;` if he uses operator overloading).

Comment: @TanmoyKrishnaDas Overloaded operators are just functions, nothing more *efficient* (as the word is normally understood in programming context) about them. Also, there are reasons to prefer free friend functions instead of methods for overloaded operators.

Comment: Complex number have some very difficult and confusing operations. It will be hundred times harder for him if he tries to implement those operations using friend functions. His code will become buggy and as he will have to improvise to solve these bugs, his code will become more unstable and less efficient. So, in a overall picture his code will ultimately become less efficient. In such a small example it might be more efficient to use friend functions but in a larger scale, it is quite unpractical to implement complex operations of complex numbers using friend functions.

Comment: Friend functions are preferable in many cases. But complex number is not one of them

Comment: You imported all of `std` into the global namespace and there is a `std::complex` already, which may or may not be what you actually want. That said, it would be helpful if you first reduced your code to the bare minimum required to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @TanmoyKrishnaDas You still haven't explained how using operator overloading would make the code more efficient.

Comment: @juanchopanza Ow! I did not think you were talking about the programming term "efficient". I wanted to say maintainable. But 5 minutes had passed so I could not edit my comment. In this example operator overloading would not result in a change of efficiency as he is just adding 2 complex numbers. But when you combine complex numbers with real world problems (mostly required in mathematics) you will see the benefits. I know because I participated in developing a library to implement complex numbers in calculus. The change of efficiency comes when you use it in integration or some other stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you declare a friend function like that, it's *still* a normal non-member function which means you call it as

```
complex cres = friendfun(c1, c2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to add a friend function. You will have to use operator overloading, and then friend it like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class complex
{
    float x, y;
public:
    complex()
    {

    }

    complex(float real, float img)
    {
        x = real;
        y = img;
    }

friend complex operator+(complex,complex);
    void display(void);
};

complex operator+(complex c,complex d)
{
    complex t;
    t.x = d.x + c.x;
    t.y = d.y + t.y;
    return(t);
};

void complex::display(void)
{
    cout << x << "+i" << y << endl;
}




int main()
{
    complex c1, c2, c3;
    c1 = complex(2.5, 3.5);
    c2 = complex(1.5, 5.5);
    c3 = c1 + c2;//c3=opra+(c1,c2)
    cout << "C1:" << endl;
    c1.display();
    cout << "C2:" << endl;
    c2.display();
    cout << "C3:" << endl;
    c3.display();
}
```